# Redirect to Apache built-in 404 page with mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Is there a way to actively serve Apache's **default, built-in 404 page** for a number of URLs using mod_rewrite? Not a custom error document, but a rule like

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/dirname/pagename
RewriteRule -- serve 404 page -----
```

I know how to build a PHP page that sends the 404 header and have `mod_rewrite` redirect all the URLs there but I would prefer a solution that is based on `mod_rewrite` only.

I just had the idea of redirecting to a non-existent address:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/dirname/pagename
RewriteRule .* /sflkadsölfkasdfölkasdflökasdf
```

but that would give the user the message **"/sflkadsölfkasdfölkasdflökasdf does not exist"** on the error page, which looks a bit unprofessional.

Comment: Voter to close: mod_rewrite questions are officially all right on SO.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39063/mod-rewrite-questions-getting-migrated-to-sf

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can use the `R` flag on the [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) to force a redirect with a given status code:

> While this is typically used for redirects, any valid status code can be given here. If the status code is outside the redirect range (300-399), then the Substitution string is dropped and rewriting is stopped as if the L flag was used.

So this:

```
RewriteRule ^/?page\.html$ - [R=404]
```

would return the default 404 page for `/page.html`. Since this is a regexp, remember the escaping `\.` and anchoring `$`.

`-` is ignored (i.e. "the Substitution string is dropped"), but there still needs to be something there to keep the rule well-formed.

Comment: Mmm not sure whether that would trigger the default error page, would it? Because I would have to put some value to `whatever` and it would redirect there wouldn't it? I may be wrong though, I'll try it out and report.

Comment: No, as the quote says, it ignores the Substitution string (i.e. the "whatever" in my example).

Comment: @mercator works like a charm, only the `/` in `RewriteRule ^/page.html` needs to be removed.

Comment: @Pekka, excellent! And fixed. I kinda neglected everything other than the `[R=404]`. The rest works the same as usual anyway.

Comment: The presence or absence of a leading "/" depends on whether the rewrite rule is in the global configuration (where it exists) or an .htaccess (where it's stripped by the [filename-to-URL mapping](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewrite_tech.html)). Use `/?` for a subpattern that will work in either context.

Comment: This is not "the best" way to do it. Best way is to carefully think where your `public` directory is located. E.g. `/var/www/some_site/public/` and `/var/www/some_site/secret_system_dir/` would be good design – although another, equally good option is to direct your traffic through `index.php`, and then exclude certain subfolders or files from an exclude-list that you feed to your **router**. Don't forget that things can also be done on the app-level, and performance overhead is negligible in most cases anyway, especially since the number of such 404's is very low compared to legit traffic.

Answer (score 14):

The best way to do that is to set the *R* flag with the status code 404:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/dirname/pagename
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
```

But this is only available since Apache 2.

Comment: or for clarity, spell it out as [redirect=404].

Comment: often, NC is another good ingredient. Remember that normales filesmatch-Forbid from All might be safer, if RewriteEngine could potentially be off.

Answer (score 4):

I confirm that

```
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^ - [L,redirect=404]
```

won't work. Here is the explanation from the official Apache website:

> However, if a status code is outside the redirect range (300-399) then
>   the substitution string is dropped entirely, and rewriting is stopped
>   as if the L were used.

So the best solution is to redirect to a 404.php file with the 404 header as explained later.

Comment: The Apache httpd docs for both 2.2 and 2.4 specify that *any* (emphasis theirs) valid status code may be returned, and does not have to be a 3xx code, in the sentence immediately before the one you quoted. The one you quoted only indicates that the substitution string is not used, which is what `-` would have done anyway. Both the examples you provided should work.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/page.html /error404.html [L]
```

That won't give the 404 header though. You could try chaning to flag to `[L,R=404]` but I doubt that will work (it's supposed to be for redirects only).

Your idea of doing so in PHP would work. If all your "error pages" pages are server-side (i.e. PHP) then you could simply use this code:

```
<?php
header( 'HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found' );
include 'error404.html';
```

Comment: Yup, this is probably what I'm going to end up with. I'm curious though whether there is a way to trigger Apache's built-in error page (without having to create one myself.) Something like a rewrite rule "trigger internal 404 handling if this URL matches."

Comment: This solution is what I used more or less, except I think I simply redirected to a non-existent page handled by `index.php`– now I would recommend instead doing it on the app-level, as it allows for far greater flexibility and control over user access to static files as well as dynamic resources. You could just feed a list of directories and files to your **router** that you want to 404 out. Depending on your CMS, if not supported, you may need to do this from a *decorator* or modify the routing code yourself. Keep in mind, performance is usually negligible in this scenario of 404's.