# htaccess mod_rewrite, difference between [L] and [R=301,L]

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So what is the difference?

Will the browser cache the 301 and remember it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The main difference between the flags `[L]` and `[R=301,L]` is that the [*R* flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r) causes an explicit external HTTP redirect (there is [one exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447106/redirect-to-apache-built-in-404-page-with-mod-rewrite)) while without the *R* flag the rule could also cause just an implicit internal redirect, depending on the actual rule and request.

The optional status code just specifies the type of the redirection response. [301 denotes a permanent redirect](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.3.2):

> The requested resource has been assigned a new permanent URI and any
> future references to this resource SHOULD use one of the returned
> URIs.  Clients with link editing capabilities ought to automatically
> re-link references to the Request-URI to one or more of the new
> references returned by the server, where possible. This response is
> cacheable unless indicated otherwise.

The two latter sentences do also answer your question, whether such a response is cacheable.