# Webserver: Fileaccess only for scripts on the server, not browsers of visitors?

Tags: php, apache, permissions, chmod

Silly question, but I'm stuck. After month, I want to go live with my project and thought: preventing pagevisitors from accessing files that are not created for direct user access - CHMOD will do this in seconds for you...

The situation-  This is the tree of my root folder:

```
/index.php
/content/home.php
/content/page2.php
```

It's kind of a template system. Index.php is the wrapper. And home.php or page2.php are files with the page content. Common situation I thought. So I changed the filepermission with filezilla of the folder "content" and all subfolders an files to Owner permission "read, write, execute = yes" and Group and Public to none.

But if I try to access www.mypage.com/content/home.php the access is given.

Thought CHMOD restricts the access via browser (public permission) and only gives index.php the right to access the files and include them within index.php.

Comment: It'd be better to store those files outside of the document root, and then clients _definitely_ can't access them, even if you accidentally reset folder permissions.

Comment: Read this in another post. But I can't access the pre root level, cause I'm on a shared server.

Comment: You can still do that on most shared servers afaik - your doc root is in "public_html" or similar, but you should have access to one level above that. Failing that, you can always deny access using an ".htaccess" file in your "content" folder.

Comment: No, I hosting on 1und1.de a german hoster. Thinks its known as 1and1.com in US. Can't go above the root folder. But thank you for your answer. I think I will I'll use the .htaccess . Is there a way to output a 404 with htaccess?

Comment: Yep, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447106/redirect-to-apache-built-in-404-page-with-mod-rewrite).

Answer (score 1):

You're over-thinking it.

```
//index.php
define('VERSION', '0.1');

///content/home.php
if(!defined('VERSION')) return;
```

add that check to all your pages, tada.

Comment: Thank you. This one works. But I have template graphics and pdf files that have to be stored somewhere. It's not the end of the world if someone gets access to this files. But I realy thought CHMOD is the solution. Maybe .htaccess is a solution. Can I output an error 404 via htaccess for "hidden" folders?

Comment: You can or just put them somewhere else and access them through a php script.