# Redirect based on rules and error type htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been trying to piece together my .htaccess file, I have not found a lot of information about what I am trying to accomplish or if I am over thinking it.

I am using the following to disable directory browsing it works but I would like to redirect it to a custom 404 error page I have created.

```
# Disable Directory Browsing
Options All -Indexes
```

Deny access to directories or files I am using the following

```
####
# Deny access to certain directories that SHOULD NOT be exposed.
####
RewriteRule ^error/ - [L,R=403]
RewriteRule ^assets/ - [L,R=403]
RewriteRule ^plugins/ - [L,R=403]
RewriteRule ^libraries/ - [L,R=403]
RewriteRule ^includes/ - [L,R=403]
RewriteRule ^bootstrap.php - [L,R=404]
```

all of these work as it should but I want to redirect to a custom error page in my script folder

example.com/errors/

All i have found is this

```
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/error-404.html
```

but have been unsuccessful in getting any of the errors redirected to the one I created.

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps this syntax might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447106/redirect-to-apache-built-in-404-page-with-mod-rewrite

Comment: You are triggering a 403 in most of those directives, but you've only defined an `ErrorDocument` for a 404? Does `/bootstrap.php` not trigger a 404 either? I'm also curious why you need to explicitly trigger a 403 for "certain directories" when you have already disabled directory browsing (`-Indexes`)? Do you have a `DirectoryIndex` document in these directories? Presumably you have a `RewriteEngine On` directive as well?

Comment: @IronMan The syntax in that linked question is the same as used here. (?)

Comment: @MrWhite well yes I have 403 and 404 the 403 is forbidden I was trying with both 403 and 404 trying to get them to redirect to a custom error, I have several reasons why I would like to accomplish this, because I want to call the custom error pages not the server side error which makes you site look like it broke. I don't want to be repetitive and put a index file with redirect in header for each directory

Comment: @IronMan that post says he dont want to redirect to a custom error but Apache default

Comment: (Just to clarify... you are not "redirecting" here. The ErrorDocument is served by an internal subrequest, the same as when the Apache default error is served. You can trigger a "redirect", but that does not apply here.)

Comment: What other directives do you have in your `.htaccess` file? What is the _exact_ wording of the Apache response you are seeing? To clarify, you have both an `/error` and `/errors` directory - the first you are blocking and the second contains your error documents?

Comment: @MrWhite I feel stupid LOL i was calling it from errors but my folder was error

Comment: In that case, you also need to remove the `RewriteRule ^error/ - [L,R=403]` directive - as mentioned in my answer - since that will block the `ErrorDocument` from being served.

Comment: @MrWhite yea i had commented it out but it got uncommitted in here some how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the actual response you are seeing or your full `.htaccess` file, my guess would be that you are blocking access to the `/errors` directory that contains your custom error documents. The error documents themselves need to be publicly accessible (although there are *tricks* you can employ to block access and serve an appropriate HTTP status code).

If you block access to the error document then Apache will fallback to the default Apache response with an additional message along the lines of:

> Additionally, a "4xx/5xx error" error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.